# HTTP 405 method not allowed - SOAP

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap

I have created a `basicHTTPBinding` .NET client that will connect to a SOAP webservice that isn't mine which is calling a JAVA service. So when trying to connect to it the error we are getting back is `HTTP 405 method not allowed` - that's all we have to go on.

(it doesn't get to the authentication stage either)

OK we are testing this via a computer that isnt controlled by us, so could it be they may not have features on their box? However, the only thing I found looking around is, the URL we are using calls a URL `WSDL?` at the end and not a `.svc` - could this be an issue?

I know there isn't a lot to go on, so I don't expect miracles from you guys but any advice would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: `method` in your error message refers to a HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS). Please provide more details on the request you are making.

Comment: Thanks - well, I am just calling a method from their WDSL so its not like MVC when I am specifying what HEAD options to use..

Comment: 405 means you are using the wrong method to access that resource, e.g. GET on a POST resource